# Laravel get each of lines from textarea and insert into new row in database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to get each of lines from textarea and insert into new row in database. So, when I write a list of text with new brakelines f.ex:
test1
test2
test3
I want to insert each of these multilines into new row in MySql f.ex:
 id kwName
 1. test1
 2. test2
 3. test3

PLease, help me.

My code is:

**Blade**

```
<textarea rows="1" name="kwName" class="form-control" placeholder="Insert keywords list"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="add_kw" value="save">
```

**Controller**

```
if ($request->has('add_kw')) {

                $this->validate($request,[
                  'kwName'=> 'required',
                ]);

                // create new data              

                $values = new keyword;

                $values->kwName = $request->kwName;
                $values->website_id = $id;
                $values->save();
}
```

Comment: use foreach loop while insertion

Comment: You should be able to break apart the text area on `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will help you::

```
<?php
  $text = trim($_POST['textareaname']); 
  $textAr = explode("\n", $text);  // remove the last \n or whitespace character
  $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); // remove any extra \r characters left behind

  foreach ($textAr as $line) {
      // processing here. 
  }
?>
```

This is just example use it as your need.

Comment: It helped me a lot, but now it is duplicating records f.ex when i write: test1 test2, in the table displayed test1 test2 next row again test test2. I don't know why

Comment: Please give the full example

Comment: $text = $_POST['kwName'];
                  $textAr = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $text));
                  $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim'); 

                  foreach ($textAr as $line) {

                        // create new data              

                        $line = new keyword;

                        $line->kwName = $request->kwName;
                        $line->website_id = $id;
                        $line->save();
                  }

Comment: The field you want not to be duplicate. You can add that field as unique.

Comment: If it helped you please upvote the answer and accept it for helping others.

Comment: @R.Jonson If it helped you please upvote the answer and accept it for helping others.

Comment: Better to use PHP_EOL instead of "\n".